# mongodb aggregation framework groupby multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection is like

```
{queid:'1',date:'07023/2013',topic: 'topic1'}
{queid:'2',date:'07022/2013',topic: 'topic2'}
{queid:'3',date:'07022/2013',topic: 'topic1'}
{queid:'4',date:'07023/2013',topic: 'topic1'}
```

i want my output to be like

```
{topic1:
    [ {date:'07/23/2013',count:2},
      {date:'07/22/2013',count:1}
    ]
}
```

is this possible to do it mongodb..

I tried doing this

```
que.aggregate([{$match:c},{$group:{_id:'$topic',count:{$push:'$date'}}}])
```

which gives output as

```
{
        "_id" : "topic",
        "count" : [
                "2013-06-04",
                "2013-06-06",
                "2013-06-17",
                "2013-06-20"
] }
```

i am nt able to understand how to group in the array and populate counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what does mean `{$match:c}` in your code. Actually, I'm a newbie in mongodb, and this code:

```
que.aggregate([
  {$group:{_id:{"topic":"$topic","date":"$date"}, sum:{$sum:1}}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id.topic", "dates":{$push:{"date":"$_id.date", "count":"$sum"}} }}
])
```

produces:

```
{
  "result" : [
     {
      "_id" : "topic2",
      "dates" : [
        { "date" : "07022/2013", "count" : 1}
      ]
     },
     {
      "_id" : "topic1",
      "dates" : [
        { "date" : "07022/2013", "count" : 1},
        { "date" : "07023/2013", "count" : 2}
      ]
     }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

I think you can play with it to get what do you want.

Comment: Actually, I think this is about as far as you can get. Converting arbitrary values (such as "topic1" or "topic2") to *keys* is not really possible.

Answer (score -1):

the Map-Reduce may suit for you.

eg:

```js
map = function (){
  emit(this.topic+this.date, 1);
}

reduce = function (id, vals){
  return Array.sum(vals);
}

db.coll.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:'results'});
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/